# Angular4 - How to detect if a response is JSON or plain text with observable

Tags: angular, angular2-observables

I'm wondering if there is a way to detect the format of a response in an observable, when using a generic api service to call a variety of endpoints. Some send back JSON, others plain text.

```
this.http.get(endpoint).map(response => {
    // if JSON
    return response.json();
    // else if plain text
    return response.text();
})...
```

Comment: Check the Content-Type header.

Answer (score 3):

A `ResponseContentType` exists in the angular [doc](https://angular.io/api/http/ResponseContentType) but I never found this enum in the response object so I use a "trick" :

```
this.http.get(endpoint).map(response => {
    const contentType = res.headers.get('Content-type');
   if (contentType == 'application/json') {
    return response.json();   
   } else if (contentType == 'application/text') {
    return response.text();
   }
})...
```

if someone know where we can find the `ResponseContentType` enum please told us !

Comment: The `ResonpseContentType` is just used in the request header to indicate what response types the client accepts. Also, your solution is correct except that there can be encoding included with the type. So your "exact" string matches will not match.

Answer (score 3):

I was never able to find a built in way with Angular to verify JSON, so I just check the content type in the response header.

Here's the function I use:

```
/**
 * True of the response content type is JSON.
 */
private static isJson(value: Response): boolean {
    return /\bapplication\/json\b/.test(value.headers.get('Content-Type'));
}
```

`Content-Type` can have extra stuff in the string so I use a regex to be safe.

I would recommend failing if it's not JSON.

```
 this.http.get().map((value:Response)=>{
      if(this.isJson(value)) {
         return value;
      }
      throw value;
 });
```

You can then catch the known JSON responses later in the subscriber. Now you know all responses in the subscriber are getting JSON.

Comment: can't you just `map` ... `return value.json()` and then `.catch()` ?

Comment: @Zze you can but you loose all of the stuff in the Response object. Like the status code. If you don't need it. Just `return value.json()` is fine.

Comment: So maybe `if(value.json()) return value;`?